# Transform a pandas dataframe in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I need to apply a custom transformation to a dataframe like this:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'value': ['a'],
    'measure':[['b', 'c']]
})

transformed_df = pd.DataFrame({
    'measure': ['b', 'c'],
    'value': ['a', 'a']
})
```

What's an efficient way of getting from `df` to `transformed_df`?

Comment: What is the logic of the transformation?

Comment: It defines a relationship between value and measure, I need to get the opposite of what we have in the data frame.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try, [`pd.DataFrame.explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html):

```
df.explode('measure').reset_index(drop=True)
```

Output:

```
  value measure
0     a       b
1     a       c
```

Answer (score 1):

One approach to the problem would be to think of it as constructing a MultiIndex:

```
value =  ['a']
measure = ['b','c']
idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([value,measure], names = ['value','measure'])

df = pd.DataFrame(index=idx).reset_index()
```

where df is:

```
  value measure
0     a       b
1     a       c
```

Having never seen the `explode` method before, I was curious to do some timing tests:

```
def test_multi(value, measure):
    idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([value,measure], names = ['value','measure'])

    df = pd.DataFrame(index=idx).reset_index()
    
    return df

def test_explode(df):
    return df.explode('measure').reset_index(drop=True)


value =  ['a']*10000
measure = ['b','c']*10000

%timeit test_multi(value, measure)
#13 s ± 116 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

value =  ['a']*10000
measure = [['b','c']]*10000


df = pd.DataFrame({
    'value': value,
    'measure':measure
})

%timeit test_explode(df)
#16.9 ms ± 199 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```